# dataset import error for AutoML text classification

Tags: machine-learning, google-natural-language, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I have trying to import dataset into AutoML NL Text Classification. However, the Ui gave me an error of Invalid row in CSV file , Error details: Error detected:  "FILE_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED"

I am uploading the csv file, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there is no hidden quotes in your dataset. Complete requirements can be found on “[Preparing your training data](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare)” page.

> Common .csv errors:
>
> - Using Unicode characters in labels. For example, Japanese characters are not supported.
> - Using spaces and non-alphanumeric characters in labels.
> - Empty lines.
> - Empty columns (lines with two successive commas).
> - Missing quotes around embedded text that includes commas.
> - Incorrect capitalization of Cloud Storage text paths.
> - Incorrect access control configured for your text files. Your service account should have read or greater access, or files must be publicly-readable.
> - References to non-text files, such as JPEG files. Likewise, files that are not text files but that have been renamed with a text extension will cause an error.
> - The URI of a text file points to a different bucket than the current project. > > - Only files in the project bucket can be accessed.
> - Non-CSV-formatted files.